# Include rollup field in other rollup calculation

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have three entities. There is 1:N relationship between `entity1` and `entity2`. There is also 1:N relationship between `entity2` and `entity3`.

`Entity2` has `subgrid` representing `entity3` records, and `total` field that calculates `entity3` `price` field values. This works fine.

There is also subgrid on `entity1` representing `entity2` records and it includes `total` `rollup` filed. When i try to make new `sum` field that should be `rollup` and calculate sum of of all `total` field, there is not and option in `rollup` settings to add that field.

Is it possible to include `rollup fileds` in other `rollup` calculation, or I might have some other problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Milos,

You cannot use nested rollup fields. Detailed information you can fine in this article - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832162.aspx in paragraph Rollup Fields Considerations:

> ### Rollup field considerations
>
> You should be aware of certain conditions and restrictions when working with rollup fields:
>
> - You can define a maximum of 100 rollup fields for the organization and up to 10 rollup fields per entity.
> - A workflow can’t be triggered by the rollup field updates.
> - A workflow wait condition cannot use a rollup field.
> - **A rollup over the rollup field is not supported.**

Comment: Completely and utterly lame. There's just no good reason for this that Microsoft couldn't have remedied. At a minimum, they should've explained this.